# Jenkins on AWS EC2 instance unable to use instance profile after upgrade

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I had a Jenkins 2.46 installation running on an EC2 box, associated to a IAM role through an instance profile.

Jenkins was able to do various tasks requiring AWS credentials (f.e. use terraform, upload files to s3, access CodeCommit git repos) using just the instance profile role (no access key or secret keys were stored on the instance).

After upgrading to Jenkins 2.89, this is no longer the case: every task requiring authentication with AWS fails with a 403 error.

However, running a command on the instance bash as the `jenkins` user still works fine (f.e. running `sudo -u jenkins /usr/bin/aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket/` lists bucket files; running the same command into Jenkins' Script Console yelds a 403).

I read the release notes of every version from 2.46 to 2.89 but I did not find anything relevant.

Jenkins was installed and updated through `yum`, the aws cli was installed using [the bundled installer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-bundle.html) provided by AWS.

Comment: How are the tasks ran? Is it in the shell command of the Jenkins jobs?

Comment: @CélineAussourd some tasks run through the "Execute shell" build step; but the problem also arise when setting the git repo (git credential helper should use the aws-cli to access the CodeCommit repo, but it fails)

Comment: What does the git config look like for the Jenkins user?